# "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation": why does example program work with just gcc but not with -m32?

Tags: c, gcc

The following code is from "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation" 2nd edition called input.c

```
 int main() {
    char message[10];
    int count, i;
    strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");
    printf("Repeat how many times? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    for(i=0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%3d - %s\n", i, message);
    }
```

This seems like a memory error(overflow) to me since the array *message* is only for 10 bytes. 
However, when I compile this with just gcc and execute the program, it runs fine.

When I add in a flag gcc -m32 to the compilation process, I get Abort trap 6 or errors that signify something is wrong ( I tried this on my personal mac and on my college's linux computer cluster to see whether there is different. On the latter, there is more of an explicit error of stack smashing with memory map and backtrace, while with my mac there is only Abort Trap 6).

Anyway, here are my questions: Why does the code work for just gcc  and not gcc -m32 ? 
Additionally, why is it that after I compile the file with gcc -m32, if I try to compile the file again with just gcc, it still won't work?

There are multiple things I don't understand, so any additional information on why this all is happening is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of gcc is it? Try `gcc --version` As for the second question, try to remove all `.o` files between compiles.

Comment: Isn't strcpy simply writing past the end of the buffer and, by chance, this doesn't overwrite anything important?

Comment: @Prof.Falken how do I list all the .o files in a directory? I usually have a make file that does rm -f $(programs) core *.o, but with gcc, how do you list and remove the .o files?

Comment: also, for versions, they are configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0 Thread model: posix;
And for linux, gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: @vvayne, that should do.

Answer (score 4):

Writing beyond arrays(and reading beyond them too) is undefined behavior, so it's just a coincidence that it depends on compiler options.

Comment: Ah, that is it. My guess is that a non broken program would work with -m32.

Comment: The way local variables are stored on the stack and how procedure calls manipulate the stack should be pretty much the same on both 32 and 64 bit architectures. While it is undefined behavior I still find it interesting that the program crashes with -m32

Comment: @SeriousBusiness- here's a way in could happen. `message` needs 14 bytes to hold the string, including the trailing null-byte. You allocated 10. On 32-bit code, the next thing up on the stack, probably the frame header, needs to be 4-byte aligned so `message` is padded to 12 bytes, still not enough. However, on 64-bit code, the frame header (or whatever) needs 8-byte alignment so `message` is padded out to 16-bytes, more than enough. I'm not saying that this is exactly what is happening but it shows what can happen.